# create a stripplot with different colors and markers- override problem

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I want to create a stripplot that contain data with different colors and markers.
**The problem:** the y-axis value is overridden by the last data entering the graph.

How can I fix this problem?

*The code:*

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn

    data1 = {"days": ["Monday", "Monday"], "Pay": [6,9]}
    data2 = {"days": ["Thursday", "Thursday"], "Pay": [5,4]}

    seaborn.stripplot(x="Pay", y="days", data=data1, dodge=True,palette=["red"], marker="^",linewidth=1)
    seaborn.stripplot(x="Pay", y="days", data=data2, dodge=True,palette=["blue"], marker="o",linewidth=1)

    plt.grid(color='green', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

*The stripplot I get :*
[image]
*what I want to get:*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New update:** This can be solved either via the `order=` keyword, or via explicitly making the data categorical.

Pandas' `pd.Categorical` can set an explicit ordering:

```
import pandas as pd
all_days = ["Monday", "Thursday"]
data1["days"] = pd.Categorical(data1["days"], all_days)
data2["days"] = pd.Categorical(data2["days"], all_days)
```

A simpler approach uses the `order=` keyword

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

data1 = {"days": ["Monday", "Monday"], "Pay": [6, 9]}
data2 = {"days": ["Thursday", "Thursday"], "Pay": [5, 4]}

all_days = ["Monday", "Thursday"]

seaborn.stripplot(x="Pay", y="days", data=data1, order=all_days, dodge=True, palette=["red"], marker="^", linewidth=1)
seaborn.stripplot(x="Pay", y="days", data=data2, order=all_days, dodge=True, palette=["blue"], marker="o", linewidth=1)

plt.grid(color='green', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.stripplot() reset limits]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I ran your code, and got the same graph I got earlier. Do you have an explanation for why?

Comment: @Mr.T if I change it to scatterplot I get an error

Comment: Your answer worked for me! Thank you!!!